# symfony 2 "This form should not contain extra fields." validation error and issues in binding REST request data

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to use Symfony forms to handle REST requests.

I was facing issue with binding request data in symfony form. While going through Symfony's code, I found it uses

```
HttpFoundationRequestHandler->handleRequest
```

In that, for POST,

```
        if ('' === $name) {
            $params = $request->request->all();
            $files = $request->files->all();
        } elseif ($request->request->has($name) || $request->files->has($name)) {
            $default = $form->getConfig()->getCompound() ? array() : null;
            $params = $request->request->get($name, $default);
            $files = $request->files->get($name, $default);
        } else {
            // Don't submit the form if it is not present in the request
            return;
        }
```

If you see above code, if there is form name in Our form type class, it tries to get values from request as

$request->request->get($name) // $name is form name.

This may work if we render form as HTML but if we post request through REST, it doesnt find data.

To make it work we either have to namespace it like below in request (I haven't tested personally this but have read it somewhere)

```
{
    'form_name': {
      'field1' => 'value1'
    }
}
```

Only below requst doesnt't bind data

```
{
  'field1' => 'value1'
}
```

or we will have to return form name as null from getName from form type so that it use root namespace.

```
public function getName()
{
    return null;
}
```

If we return null, then it creates other problem, if there are any extra parameters in request other than form fields it gives validation errors.

```
"This form should not contain extra fields."
```

Ideally form should just fetch the feild values from request which are configured in form and should ignore any other request parameters which are unknowne to it.

e.g. if this is the form

```
class SampleFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('field1', 'text', array('constraints' => new NotBlank()))
            ->add('field2', 'password', array('constraints' => new NotBlank()));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but in request if I am sending

```
{
   'field1' => 'value1',
   'field2' => 'value2',
   'field3' => 'value3'
}
```

It gives above validation errors. It should ideally simply ignore field3 and fetch feild1 & field2 from request.

If we compare code in  NativeRequestHandler & HttpFoundationRequestHandler,

NativeRequestHandler seem to have handled it properly

```
        if ('' === $name) {
            $params = $_POST;
            $files = $fixedFiles;
        } elseif (array_key_exists($name, $_POST) || array_key_exists($name, $fixedFiles)) {
            $default = $form->getConfig()->getCompound() ? array() : null;
            $params = array_key_exists($name, $_POST) ? $_POST[$name] : $default;
            $files = array_key_exists($name, $fixedFiles) ? $fixedFiles[$name] : $default;
        } else {
            // Don't submit the form if it is not present in the request
            return;
        }
```

where as HttpFoundationRequestHandler doesn't

```
        if ('' === $name) {
            $params = $request->request->all();
            $files = $request->files->all();
        } elseif ($request->request->has($name) || $request->files->has($name)) {
            $default = $form->getConfig()->getCompound() ? array() : null;
            $params = $request->request->get($name, $default);
            $files = $request->files->get($name, $default);
        } else {
            // Don't submit the form if it is not present in the request
            return;
        }
```

So either we need to be able to use NativeRequestHandler or we need fix in HttpFoundationRequestHandler ?

I see below works though only in case of content-type text request (doesnt work with application/json),

```
$form->submit(array('field1' => $request->request->get('field1'), 'field2' => $request->request->get('field2')))
```

But using $form->handleRequest($request) looks more simpler and abstract.

If there is any other better and simpler solution please do suggest.

Comment: You're sending `field1` in you request but the form has field named `feild`. Typo?

Comment: yeah sorry its type in this question. Real application field names are different.

Comment: Few days ago I achieved this exact thing. Not exactly via `REST` but via `AngularJS` - still  I didn't print my form using Twig's `form_*` functions. I try to fig it out and see what I did there.

Comment: well written question...I've the same problem. How did you resolve this in the end?

Comment: I am using  {
    'form_name': {
      'field1' => 'value1'
    }
}

Comment: I've got the same issue as well. Although to me it looks like the NativeRequestHandler is replacing all the form data with the file upload form.

Comment: I've posted a issue here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13746